# Autobahn Exception WebSockets protocol violation

Tags: android, websocket, jetty, autobahn

in my android application I want to use the autobahn library to use websockets.

I think the server is using draft-17.
Can someone tell me, how to set up the Client to use this protocol?

I have this code:

```
      mConnection.connect(url,new String[] {"protocolname?"}, new WebSocketHandler() {

         //some functions
      },options);
```

Greetings

**UPDATE**
On my server I use Jetty in version 8.1.

**UPDATE** 
the output from LogCat is:

```
01-15 22:54:53.481: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(32452): created
01-15 22:54:53.491: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(32452): WS reader created     and started
01-15 22:54:53.491: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(32452): running
01-15 22:54:53.491: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter(32452): created
01-15 22:54:53.491: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(32452): WS writer created and started
01-15 22:54:53.551: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(32452): opening handshake received
01-15 22:54:53.551: D/Websocket(32452): Status: Connected to ws://192.168.178.30:8080
01-15 22:54:53.551: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(32452): run() : WebSocketException (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketException: RSV != 0 and no extension negotiated)
01-15 22:54:53.551: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(32452): ended
01-15 22:54:53.551: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(32452): fail connection [code = 4, reason = WebSockets protocol violation
01-15 22:54:53.551: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(32452): quit
01-15 22:54:53.551: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter(32452): ended
01-15 22:54:53.551: D/Websocket(32452): Connection lost.
01-15 22:54:53.551: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(32452): worker threads stopped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to WebSocket protocol version or WebSocket subprotocols?

Regarding the former: AutobahnAndroid implements RFC6455 (the last and final WebSocket protocol version). There is no way to downgrade to older versions, but basically, there haven't been significant changes from Hybi-10+ to RFC6455.

Regarding the latter: WebSocket subprotocols are specified when opening the WebSocket connection like [this](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/master/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WampConnection.java#L192).

Comment: Yeah the WebSocket Protocol. Thanks for this information. Do you know how to set up Jetty 8.1 to the RFC6455 standard?

Comment: Nope, sorry. But probably you don't need to do anything special. The WebSocket protocol version is announced and negotiated during the initial WebSocket opening handshake between the 2 peer's implementations.

Comment: okay, my problem is that my android client is getting disconnected after it is connected. The exception is calling: `D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(6471): fail connection [code = 4, reason = WebSockets protocol violation´

Comment: try enabling debug output so you can see the actual violation: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/master/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketReader.java#L672

Comment: i had. I posted the output to the main question

Comment: The relevant log message for the protocol violation detected is `RSV != 0 and no extension negotiated`. The server sent a WebSocket frame with a reserved bit set - that is only allowed for WebSocket extensions negotiated. I'd ask Jetty developers what could be the cause.

Comment: Hi Oberstet I am using Android Autobhan libary for client side and server side Crossbar(Node.js) when i tried to connect connection opened successfully then immediately connection closed and the error is websockets protocol violation please let me know where the problem is..? thanks

Comment: @MunishKapoor AutobahnAndroid is till WAMP1, not yet WAMP2

Comment: Hi @oberstet, i have some problem too. can you explain ho to fix it? I am using Android Autobahn library for client and server side is Socket.IO .